# Java enum var types are not compatible with the reference types they originated from

Tags: java, enums

I have a couple classes that reuse the same constants, so I created an enum with those constants.

```
public enum PopularRecipes{
    LASAGNA (new Recipe("LASAGNA", 35, true, "Meat, Cheese, Onions, Garlic, Noodles"))
}
```

But when I try to use these constants with a method that accepts the underlying types like:

```
class BlueBook {
     private final Recipes PAGE_ONE = new Recipes().addRecipe(PopularRecipes.LASAGNA)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
The method addRecipe(Recipe) in the type Recipes is not applicable for the arguments (PopularRecipes)
```

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something critical about enums, but nothing I see online implies that this wouldn't work. Does someone mind explaining to me why the underlying enum vars have changed types?

Comment: Renjith, rzwitserloot, and Reilas, thank you so much for all of your help. I've come to realize that the enum data structure is not what I needed for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what enums are for.

Enums represent a **type** (such as, say, 'Tree', or 'Recipe') that has the following properties:

- It is final - there is no need to subclass it. You won't be needing, say, 'VegetarianRecipe' or 'DeciduousTree'. In other words, the 'members' of the type do not need to change for specific species of this type (i.e. if DeciduousTree needs to have a `getLeafFallMonth()` method but non-deciduous trees shouldn't have that method at all, there is a difference in what members are exposed for different species. In which case, **enums are not appropriate**).
- There are a limited number of instances that can ever exist for this type, and they can **all** be fully and entirely specified at code-write time by the author who made that type. If, for example, it is possible to add recipes (in addition to, say, a bunch of common recipes that the app ships out of the box), then **enums are not appropriate**.

If the above accurately describes recipes, then `Recipe` *itself* needs to be the enum:

```
public enum Recipe {
  LASAGNA("LASAGNA", 35, true, "Meat, Cheese, Onions, Garlic, Noodles"),
  PIZZA(....),
  ;

  Recipe(String code, int price, boolean containsMeaet, String ingredients) {
  ....
}
}
```

is how to do it. If either one doesn't apply, then *do not use enum at all*, that's not what they are for. You would, presumably, want exposed constants. Looks like:

```
public Recipe {
  public Recipe(String code, int price, boolean containsMeaet, String ingredients)
  { ....}

  public static final Recipe LASAGNA = new Recipe("LASAGNA", 35, ...);
}
```

There is no need for `PopularRecipes`. If you really want it, it would be a class whose only purpose is as a container for `public static final Recipe LASAGNA` and other popular recipes. To ensure nobody tries something silly, like instantiate a new instance of PopularRecipes, add a constructor, make it `private`.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `LASAGNA` is `PopularRecipes`, but your `addRecipe` method accepts only `Recipe` type.

In java, each enum constant's is of type enum itself. So here the type of `LASAGNA` is `PopularRecipes`

What you can do is may be add a method into `PopularRecipes` to get the `Recipe` associated with each enum type and use it like

```
new Recipes().addRecipe(PopularRecipes.LASAGNA.getAssociatedReceipe())
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may just be misunderstanding the error.

```
The method addRecipe(Recipe) in the type Recipes is not applicable for the arguments (PopularRecipes)
```

This is because the *addRecipe* method has a *Recipe* parameter type, and not a *PopularRecipes* type.

The solution is to create a method within *PopularRecipes*, to return the *Recipe* value.

```java
public enum PopularRecipes{
    LASAGNA (new Recipe("LASAGNA", 35, true, "Meat, Cheese, Onions, Garlic, Noodles"));

    private Recipe recipe;

    PopularRecipes(Recipe recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    public Recipe getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }
}
```

Then, you can apply the method call, to your *addRecipe* argument.

```java
private final Recipes PAGE_ONE = new Recipes().addRecipe(PopularRecipes.LASAGNA.getRecipe())
```

As an alternative, you can have the *addRecipe* method do the parsing.
So, you can still offer just the *enum* value.

```java
public Recipes addRecipe(PopularRecipes popularRecipes) {
    Recipe recipe = popularRecipes.getRecipe();
    
}
```

> *"... I feel like I'm misunderstanding something critical about enums ..."*

There are many applications for *enum* sets, and not necessarily one way to abstract it.

What you're using is fine, although, there is a better way to organize this data.

Consider the following examples.

Since you are utilizing the recipe name in more than one form, create an *enum* for it.
I'll add a new *Recipe*, also, to convey the example.

```java
enum RecipeName {
    Lasagna, BakedZiti
}
```

Additionally, since an ingredient can be used in many different recipes, create an *enum* for this as well.
This will remove any possible bugs that can arrive from typographical errors, common with manually entered text values—especially when you are typing the same value, repeatedly.

```java
enum Ingredient {
    Meat, Cheese, Onions, Garlic, Noodles,
    Ziti, TomatoSauce
}
```

Now, your *Recipe* class can utilize both of these.
As a note, I was unsure what your *boolean* value was, so I just named it *"value"*.

```java
class Recipe {
    RecipeName name;
    String price;
    boolean value;
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    Recipe(RecipeName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    void addIngredients(Ingredient... ingredients) {
        this.ingredients.addAll(List.of(ingredients));
    }
}
```

Additionally, your *PopularRecipes* class can be a static structure.
And, since I'm re-using both *RecipeName* and *Ingredient* multiple times, I've added them as static imports.

```java
import static Ingredient.*;
import static RecipeName.*;
```

```java
class PopularRecipes {
    static List<Recipe> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        Recipe lasagna = new Recipe(Lasagna);
        lasagna.setPrice("35");
        lasagna.setValue(true);
        lasagna.addIngredients(Meat, Cheese, Onions, Garlic, Noodles);
        list.add(lasagna);

        Recipe bakedZiti = new Recipe(BakedZiti);
        bakedZiti.setPrice("20");
        bakedZiti.addIngredients(Ziti, Cheese, TomatoSauce, Garlic);
        list.add(bakedZiti);
    }

    /** @return null if not found */
    static Recipe getRecipe(RecipeName recipeName) {
        for (Recipe recipe : list) {
            if (recipe.name == recipeName) return recipe;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Organizing the data in this fashion improves scalability, for appending a collection of recipes.

There are numerous ways to contain the data, this is just an example.